# Entityframework Insert into Table FK Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables User and Activity

The tables are:

1. **User table** has two columns ( userid PK, username )
2. **Activity table** has three columns (ActivityId PK, Location, userid FK) the activity table references the user table with the userid

using Entity Framework, i scaffolded the database with these table. Then i wrote the code to insert into the **user table**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult createUser(User user)
    {
        using(var context =  new postgresContext())
        {
            var c = new User()
            {
                Userid = user.Userid,
                Username = user.Username
            };

            context.Users.Add(c);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

however, i get the error below

```
     {
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-0dedc95e91a6fdb2e9da01333f7d19ff-b2605a6c7e5bd5d4-00",
  "errors": {
    "user": [
      "The user field is required."
    ],
    "$.activities[0].user": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to GISSolution.API.LearnModel.User. Path: $.activities[0].user | LineNumber: 8 | BytePositionInLine: 22."
    ]
  }
}
```

The model in swagger is

```
{
  "userid": 0,
  "username": "string",
  "activities": [
    {
      "activityid": 0,
      "location": "string",
      "userid": 0,
      "user": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to insert into the user table but the model is structured with the activity. please how do i approach this?

Comment: I have edited. I am using EF Core. the code does not give me an error, but when i want to run from swagger the request body shows nested activities table. but what i want is to insert userid and username

Comment: What's the content of the `user` parameter? Also, *you* write the code. If the API has a request object containing `activities` and you don't want that, then remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Are using PostgreSQL?  please confirm. Also seems that the user field is required,your swagger model does not contain any entry for the user field. ideally if its type is an incremental datatype, you'll have to set it up as autoincrement in the db using the serial type, see below SQL for creating a table in PostgreSQL

CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
ID  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME           TEXT      NOT NULL,
AGE            INT       NOT NULL,
ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
SALARY         REAL
);

In your model class does a relationship exists between both tables, this could be the reason why you have activity object nested.
seems there's a parent child relationship between both tables, take a look at this post in the link below, seems similar to what your are experiencing.

[Entity Framework data insertion with nested object having auto increment primary keys with one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206294/entity-framework-data-insertion-with-nested-object-having-auto-increment-primary)

Comment: Yes i am using PostgreSQL. Please why do i have the activity object nested. Is there away i can abstract that and just focus on the table i need to insert into? how does the work, i cant seem to know a way around it. Thanks

Comment: Asking for clarifications/confirmations should be done in comments, please wait until you can comment properly.